# Proper representation for a conditional function

Tags: functions

I have a function shown in below image. But the 2nd line (the parenthesis) has something that I don't know how to formulate properly.

[The equation](http://host111.com/files/equation.jpg) (I was not allowed to post images directly)

1- Does this count as a piecewise function?

2- Would someone please help me to create a proper presentation?

Thanks.

Comment: What if two of the $R$s are zero?

Comment: Write the equation down please...

Comment: @user7530: only one of them can be 0. It has a physical concept that I omitted to avoid making things more complex.

Comment: @darks: it is a model I have created. http://host111.com/files/equation1.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try to write a one-line definition of $M_i$. That's bound to end up confusing.

Instead I might first define $d(R)$ to be the least index $i$ for which $R_i=0$, or $0$ if none of the $R_i$ are zero. Then I would write, e.g.,

$$M_i(R) = \begin{cases}F(R_i) & d(R) = 0\\1 &d(R) = i\\0 & \textrm{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be more proper, still  a bit confusing.

Comment: I built another one based on your method. Is this mathematically acceptable? thanks. http://host111.com/files/equation2.jpg